# how to add Google eCommerce Tracking in our opencart site

Tags: javascript, php, opencart

I have a opencart website i need to add Google eCommerce Tracking in my opencart site how to add ? and where will add? i have a google script code but i don't know this please any one help me.

Here google Google eCommerce Tracking code how to convert our based please help:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ga('require', 'ecommerce');
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
  'id': '1234',                     // Transaction ID. Required. dynamic variable of order id
  'affiliation': 'Acme Clothing',   // Affiliation or store name. Kuberan Silks
  'revenue': '11.99',               // Grand Total. grand total dynamic variable of the price
  'shipping': '5',                  // Shipping. dynamic variable of shipping
  'tax': '1.29'                     // Tax. dynamic tax variable
});

ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
  'id': '1234',                     // Transaction ID. Required. 
  'name': 'Fluffy Pink Bunnies',    // Product name. Required.
  'sku': 'DD23444',                 // SKU/code.
  'category': 'Party Toys',         // Category or variation.
  'price': '11.99',                 // Unit price.
  'quantity': '1'                   // Quantity.
});

ga('ecommerce:send');
</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

**1.** Log into the existing or create a new account to retrieve the tracking code from: Google Analytics.

**2.** Copy the provided code.

**3.** Log into your OpenCart admin panel.

**4.** Navigate to Extensions -> Analytics:

[image]

**5.** Next to the Google Analytics title, click blue pencil icon to edit the code:
    [image]

**6.** Paste the retrieved tracking code into the text box.

**7.** Select Enabled and save changes.

**8.** Use Control/Command+U hotkeys to check the page source code. The snippet should appear before the closing tag of the page head section:

[image]

**9.** Proceed to your Google Analytics Account to track the statistics of the website.

Comment: Have you read main question? "i need to add Google eCommerce Tracking in my opencart site" You answer does not meat any main request....